# Why does this jQuery tooltip not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this tooltip:
http://osvaldas.info/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly

Here's the test page (running in WooCommerce/WordPress):
https://blendbee.com/shop/uncategorized/test-product-2/

You can see the "ingredient" under "Add-Ons" is underlined. If you put your mouse over it, the title is shown, but the jQuery tooltip doesn't appear.  The HTML for the "ingredient" is:

```
<abbr title="Here's some info about this ingredient..." rel="tooltip">ingredient</abbr>
```

In Chrome Inspect I see an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I assume it has to do with the JS function in the footer area, that I copied from the tooltip page, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
$(function(){ var targets = $( '[rel~=tooltip]' )...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to put the js which you got from the tooltip page to the head section?

Comment: @V31 - nope, because the script author said body was better.  Not to worry though, the answer below fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing `$ is not a function` in the console
but it looks like jQuery is included.

try changing

```
 $(function(){...});
```

to

```
  (function($) {
      $(function(){...});
  })(jQuery);
```